# Can I use an instance method for a computed value in a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that has a time length (minutes and seconds columns) as part of its data.  I would like to add a method to return the time formatted as mm:ss (like 09:08).  I've made a method to do this and tested it using irb.  But when I try to access the value from my view, it looks like the instance variables are not being initialized and I'm getting "00:00" for all of the values.  In looking here and elsewhere, it looks like I could make a class method (by adding self.) and pass the value in for formatting but that seems redundant.  The model instance should already have the data.  Is using a class method the ruby way?  Or am I doing something else obviously wrong?

```
class Segment  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course

  def time
    m = pad @min
    s = pad @sec
    m + ":" + s
  end 

  def pad(x)
    x.to_s.rjust(2,"0")
  end
 end

 view:
  <%= segment.time %> # returns 00:00
  <%= segment.min %>:<%= segment.sec %> # returns correct non-padded values
```

I'm using Rails 5.0.1 and Ruby 2.2.6p386.

Comment: I dont think instance variables are the problem. Id guess its something about the way your buikding the string in `time`. Try string interpolation as an answer suggests.

Comment: In terms of class methods, you can write entire programs passing everything as an argument and not storing instance state. Thid takes longer to write, but having each method be self contained can help decouple your code. The best thing to do is to try both approaches and see which one you prefer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access an ActiveRecord attribute with the assumption that each data field is stored in an instance variable. This doesn't work as attributes are stored in `@attributes` as a `ActiveRecord::AttributeSet` structure.

You can take a look at the structure using `segment.instance_method_get(:@attributes)`

Manipulating the raw data within this structure is pretty cumbersome. So AR defines attribute methods for every attribute in the class. In your case, `#min`, `#min=` or `#sec`, `#sec=` (and a bunch of other methods).

It's good practice to access data through accessor methods instead of accessing the instance variable directly. This holds true whether you're calling the method from inside or outside the class.

If you're calling the method outside the class, you need to explicitly state the receiver of the accessor method, which will be your `segment` object.

```
segment.min
```

Within your class, the receiver is implicitly defined as `self` (as Michael Kohl mentioned), so you can call the accessor directly using

```
class Segment
  def padded_min
    min to_s.rjust(2,"0")
  end
end
```

Implicit definition works a bit differently for methods which end with `=` - Ruby assumes you're creating a local variable. You need to explicitly define the receiver if you're trying to call a setter method.

```
class Segment
  def update_time(time)
    self.time = (time)
  end
end
```

Comment: You've addressed the root of my confusion!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is a much more elegant way to handle time durations.

Just use a single integer column and store the duration in the smallest level of accuracy needed (seconds). In this example we are calling the column `duration`.

```
class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  # custom getter which returns an ActiveSupport::Duration
  def duration
    self[:duration].seconds
  end

  def duration_as_time
    Time.at(self[:duration]).utc
  end

  def time
    duration_as_time.strftime("%M:%S")
  end
end
```

Note that we are using the square bracket accessors `[]`. Ruby lets you define these accessors on any class - in ActiveRecord they are used to get/set the column value.

The `duration_as_time` method gives us a Time object which is the 
unix epoch plus the duration:

```
irb(main):025:0> Time.at(360).utc
=> 1970-01-01 00:06:00 UTC
```

Having a time object lets us use purpose built methods like `strftime` instead of reinventing the wheel.

It can be argued though that formatting time is not the job of the model and should be handled by a helper or a decorator. This is especially true if you are [localizing times](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) as models are not locale aware.

Comment: Thank you!  I will definitely use this to refactor what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use instance variables? If `min` and `sec` are columns of your table, you can just use them directly (the implicit receiver will be `self`, so it's a shorter way of saying `self.min` and `self.sec`).

This should work:

```
def time
  "#{pad(min)}:#{pad(sec)}"
end
```

Generally though I'd advise to look into using helpers and/or decorators, cause what you're doing now adds 2 methods to the model that are solely used for display purposes.